# How to extract text from a html table row

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

This is my string :

```
content = '<tr class="cart-subtotal"><th>RTO / Registration office :</th><td><span class="amount"><h5>Yadgiri</h5></span></td></tr>'
```

I have tried below regular expression to extract the text which is in between h5 element tag:

```
   reg = re.search(r'<tr class="cart-subtotal"><th>RTO / Registration office :</th><td><span class="amount"><h5>([A-Za-z0-9%s]+)</h5></span></td></tr>' % string.punctuation,content)
```

It's exactly returns what I wants.

Is there any more pythonic way to get this one ?

Comment: Yes. Look at Beautiful Soup 4.

Comment: i want in regular expression instead of beautifulsoup and scrapy.

Comment: Do ***NOT*** use regex for parsing html/xml/tag-style data.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @James Thanks for the Info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dunno whether this qualifies as more pythonic or not, but it handles it as HTML data.

```
from lxml import html
content = '<tr class="cart-subtotal"><th>RTO / Registration office :</th><td><span class="amount"><h5>Yadgiri</h5></span></td></tr>'
HtmlData = html.fromstring(content)
ListData = HtmlData.xpath(‘//text()’)
```

And to get the last element:

```
ListData[-1]
```

Comment: To install on a Debian based system use python3-lxml